# even trigger set up on blob storage fails in azure factory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am setting up a event trigger on a blob storage  v2in data factory pipeline, when i publish the pipeline I keep getting this error below, i have only set up storage recently but i cant see any thing out of place, do I need to set up even subscription in blob storage and create event from the storage itself as there are option to set up automation in there

The attempt to configure storage notifications for the provided storage account hmtest1 failed. Please ensure that your storage account meets the requirements described at https://aka.ms/storageevents. The error is Failed to retrieve credentials for request=RequestUri=https://management.azure.com/subscriptions

{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant."}}

Answer (score 0):

> {"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"The received access token is not valid: at least one of the claims 'puid' or 'altsecid' or 'oid' should be present. If you are accessing as application please make sure service principal is properly created in the tenant."}}

**AFAIK**, In ADF, this error occurs when the **Data factory is not registered** in the Resource providers.
To resolve this, we need to register Data factory in the Resource Providers.

Go to **Subscriptions->your account->Resource providers** and check whether Data factory is **Registered** or not.

[image]

If it is showing as **NotRegistered** then select it and click on **Register**.

[image]

After successfully registered, create a new data factory workspace and check the Storage event trigger.

If it still gives the same error, register the **EventGrid** as well and re-check.

Comment: In my case, both synapse and eventgrid are registered but still the same issue.